# capture/parsing entries by date range

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

It is possible to capture/parsing entries with 3 days old from current date using standard module "re"?

Below sample file from where I want capture entries.

```
xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-09-2T14:13:17 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Humbly, I think you should redact again your question. The re module is for matching regular expressions and substitute them and here you're asking for extracting (not capturing) expressions more than 3 days old. This implies calculations, which re module is not designed for.
Please, include more details in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract with the re module the string with the hour and then:

```
from datetime import datetime
capturedEntries = []
THREE_DAYS = datetime.timedelta(3)

# I suppose you'are reading lines in another way, but as an example...
for entry in entries:
    # I'm assuming each entry follows the format
    # xx: xxxxxx ; xxxx: 2017-09-2T14:13:17 ; xxxxxxxx: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    stringDate = re.search(r'\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line)
    if stringDate.group():
        parsedDate = datetime.strptime(stringDate.group(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
        timeFromDate = (datetime.today() - parsedDate)
        if timeFromDate > THREE_DAYS:
            # We save only the datetimes you asked for in datetime format
            # For string format, replace parsedDate for stringDate
            capturedEntries.append(parsedDate)
```